# Analytic extension in several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be an open domain and $K \subset D$ be a compact subset such that $D - K$ is simply connected. Let furthermore $f$ be a analytic function defined on $D-K$. Is it possible to extend $f$ to the whole $D$? If yes, by which theorem. If not, what further assumption do I need in order to make it possible ($D$ beeing a polydisk, some convergence theorems etc....)? Or doesn't it work at all?

bill

Comment: I removed the tag `functional-analysis`, which did not fit the question. Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to assume that $D\setminus K$ is *connected*. Look up Hartogs' extension theorem, which you can find in any textbook on several complex variables. [Wikipedia's version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27_extension_theorem)

Of course, you need to assume that $n > 1$. If $n=1$, it's very easy to find counterexamples, e.g. $f(z) = 1/(z-p)$, where $p\in K$.)

Comment: yes but my function $f$ is not holomorphic? is the theorem also true for non-holomorphic but analytic functions?

Comment: @bill What do you mean by 'analytic'? With the usual meaning of the words, they are synonymous.

Comment: that it can be locally written in a power-series

Comment: @bill Then a function is holomorphic if and only if it is analytic (this can also be found in any textbook on the subject)

Comment: @mrf You must add something of the number of variables.

Comment: @AD. Fine, but nobody uses $\mathbb{C}^n$ when they want to include $n=1$....

Comment: Many people do not know of the huge differences between $n=1$ and $n>1$. (+1)

Comment: (I think of the inner function problem and the Corona problem..)

Comment: @bill: please suppress the tag *functional analysis* which is completely irrelevant to your question.